# VB.Net DataTable nested relationship how?

Tags: vb.net, datatable, nested, relationship

[image]

[image]

Updated: I am trying to create a XML with the schema shown in the screenshot(link). Anybody tell me how to add the relation to achieve this or modify the Datatable to achieve  this?

```
        Data_Set.Relations.Add("ProdCategory", tbl_Product.Columns("pID"), tbl_Category.Columns("cID"))
    Data_Set.Relations("ProdCategory").Nested = True

    Data_Set.Relations.Add("CatogoryItems", tbl_Category.Columns("cID"), tbl_Items.Columns("iID"))
    Data_Set.Relations("CatogoryItems").Nested = True

    'Data_Set.Relations.Add("ProdItems", tbl_Product.Columns("pID"), tbl_Iems.Columns("iID"))
    'Data_Set.Relations("ProdItems").Nested = True
```

I am stuck with the above code.

and also i should able to read xml back to dataset with read xml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks as if you are attempting to use different Parent/Child columns, Such as you are linking the productid in parent table to categoryid in child table, etc... That is going to give undesired result. My closest guess to what you want:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim DtSet As New DataSet
    With DtSet
        .Tables.Add("Product")
        With .Tables("Product")
            .Columns.Add("ProductID", GetType(String))
            .Rows.Add("P1")
            .Rows.Add("P2")
        End With

        .Tables.Add("Category")
        With .Tables("Category")
            .Columns.Add("ProductID", GetType(String))
            .Columns.Add("CategoryID", GetType(String))
            .Rows.Add("P1", "C1")
            .Rows.Add("P1", "C2")
            .Rows.Add("P2", "C3")
            .Rows.Add("P2", "C4")
        End With

        .Tables.Add("Items")
        With .Tables("Items")
            .Columns.Add("ProductID", GetType(String))
            .Columns.Add("CategoryID", GetType(String))
            .Columns.Add("Items", GetType(String))
            .Rows.Add("P1", "", "Item1")
            .Rows.Add("P2", "", "Item2")
            .Rows.Add("", "C2", "Item3")
            .Rows.Add("", "C3", "Item4")
            .Rows.Add("", "C4", "Item5")
        End With

        .Relations.Add(New DataRelation("ProductToItems", .Tables("Product").Columns("ProductID"),
                                                                  .Tables("Items").Columns("ProductID"), False))

        .Relations.Add(New DataRelation("ProductToCategory", .Tables("Product").Columns("ProductID"),
                                                                     .Tables("Category").Columns("ProductID"), False))

        .Relations.Add(New DataRelation("CategoryToItems", .Tables("Category").Columns("CategoryID"),
                                                                   .Tables("Items").Columns("CategoryID"), False))
        For Each Relation As DataRelation In .Relations
            Relation.Nested = True
        Next
    End With

    DtSet.WriteXml("C:\Data\Data.XML", XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema)

End Sub
```

Because you have null values in your example you cannot enable constraints.

Comment: Hi, there is a small problem, C2, Item 3 comes in P1 .any idea?

Comment: Hi, Im glad it worked for you. Hows about some bounty points?

Comment: since i can not enable constraints, is there a way to delete children when i delete parent ?

Comment: You would need to implement [ForeignKeyConstraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.foreignkeyconstraint?view=netframework-4.8) or in vb class you could use `GetChildRows` on parent datarow to create array of datarow, and if Array.Length >0 Delete those rows, then delete the parent.

Comment: hi, thanks.. i tried this way but when i delete Product , category still exists     parentColumn = .Tables("Product").Columns("ProductID")
    childColumn = .Tables("Category").Columns("CategoryID")
    fkeyConstraint = New ForeignKeyConstraint("ProductsFKCategory", parentColumn, childColumn)

    fkeyConstraint.DeleteRule = Rule.SetNull
    fkeyConstraint.UpdateRule = Rule.Cascade
    fkeyConstraint.AcceptRejectRule = AcceptRejectRule.Cascade

Comment: I really think you should create a new question regarding the FK procedure

Comment: Are you reading this XML into a dataset `DataSet.ReadXml()`? I will make an edit to the answer with FK's

Comment: Yes. I am reading back to XML. I have also another question posted.

Comment: Ok, well that changes things, specifically with `XmlWriteMode` You should write the mode which best fits your needs [XmlWriteMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.xmlwritemode?view=netframework-4.8) same goes for XmlReadMode when reading it back in.

Comment: So which mode should i choose? i just want to write to xml and read back exact thing.

Comment: I would use `XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema` It will not look like your desired output, however, I used ignore so it would be a better match to what you wanted. I suppose it would of been a good idea to include what you wanted to do with the resulting XML